Python open source image processing script fails after cropping original grayscale TIF image in GIMP or Python
I have an open source script for image processing that works perfectly with the images I have to process, though the area of interest is only a section of the original images. Trying to crop to just the area of interest and then running the processing script on the cropped images gives me a divide by zero error in the value of "det_a"
I don't understand image formats much at all so I can't tell what the script is doing or why it fails after cropping. I've tried cropping in both python and GIMP, I am careful to ensure the crop is exactly the same for each image and the cropped outputs are still TIFs. The divide by zero error is:
"58: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
u = (carriers[1].k_loc[0] * phis[0] - carriers[0].k_loc[0] * phis[1]) / det_a"
The input for the code in the console is:
python .\filetree\fcd.py test_output "filetree\image1.tif" "filetree\image2.tif"
this gives the resulting image in a new folder titled "test_output"
FWIW on the original grayscale images the values for
max(i_ref[0]), min(i_ref[0]) are 64,0 and on the cropped image are 82,11
on the cropped image:
carriers[1].k_loc[0] = - carriers[0].k_loc[0]
carriers[0].k_loc[1] = - carriers[1].k_loc[1]
hence why det_a is zero on the cropped image.
On original image:
carriers[0].k_loc[0] = 0
The other 3 values are non-zero and different from one another
I know either something is lost or gained in metadata for the creation of the cropped image I just have no idea what.
import time
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List
import os.path

import imageio.v2 as imageio
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from scipy.fft import fft2, ifft2, ifftshift
from skimage.draw import disk
from skimage.io import imread
from more_itertools import flatten

from fft_inverse_gradient import fftinvgrad
from find_peaks import find_peaks
from kspace import pixel2kspace


def normalize_image(img):
    return (img - img.min()) / (img.max()-img.min())

def peak_mask(shape, pos, r):
    result = np.zeros(shape, dtype=bool)
    result[disk(pos, r, shape=shape)] = True
    return result


def ccsgn(i_ref_fft, mask):
    return np.conj(ifft2(i_ref_fft * mask))


@dataclass
class Carrier:
    pixel_loc: array
    k_loc: array
    krad: float
    mask: array
    ccsgn: array


def calculate_carriers(i_ref):
    peaks = find_peaks(i_ref)
    peak_radius = np.linalg.norm(peaks[0] - peaks[1]) / 2
    i_ref_fft = fft2(i_ref)

    carriers = [Carrier(peak, pixel2kspace(i_ref.shape, peak), peak_radius, mask, ccsgn(i_ref_fft, mask)) for mask, peak
                in
                [(ifftshift(peak_mask(i_ref.shape, peak, peak_radius)), peak) for peak in peaks]]
    return carriers


def fcd(i_def, carriers: List[Carrier]):
    i_def_fft = fft2(i_def)

    phis = [-np.angle(ifft2(i_def_fft * c.mask) * c.ccsgn) for c in carriers]

    det_a = carriers[0].k_loc[1] * carriers[1].k_loc[0] - carriers[0].k_loc[0] * carriers[1].k_loc[1]
    u = (carriers[1].k_loc[0] * phis[0] - carriers[0].k_loc[0] * phis[1]) / det_a
    v = (carriers[0].k_loc[1] * phis[1] - carriers[1].k_loc[1] * phis[0]) / det_a

    return fftinvgrad(-u, -v)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    import glob
    from pathlib import Path

    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    argparser.add_argument('output_folder', type=Path)
    argparser.add_argument('reference_image', type=str)
    argparser.add_argument('definition_image', nargs='+', help='May contain wildcards')
    argparser.add_argument('--output-format', default='tiff', choices=['tiff', 'bmp', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'], help='The output format')
    argparser.add_argument('--skip-existing', action='store_true', help='Skip processing an image if the output file already exists')

    args = argparser.parse_args()
   
    args.output_folder.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    i_ref = imread(args.reference_image, as_gray=True)
    print(max(i_ref[0]), min(i_ref[0]))

    print(f'processing reference image...', end='')
    carriers = calculate_carriers(i_ref)
    print('done')

    files = list(sorted(flatten((glob.glob(x) if '*' in x else [x]) for x in args.definition_image)))

    for file in files:
        output_file_path = args.output_folder.joinpath(f'{Path(file).stem}.{args.output_format}')

        if os.path.abspath(file).lower() == os.path.abspath(output_file_path).lower():
            print(f'Warning: Skipping converting {file} because it would overwrite a input file')
            continue

        if args.skip_existing and output_file_path.exists():
            continue

        print(f'processing {file} -> {output_file_path} ... ', end='')
        i_def = imread(file, as_gray=True)
        t0 = time.time()
        height_field = fcd(i_def, carriers)
        print(f'done in {time.time() - t0:.2}s\n')

        imageio.imwrite(output_file_path, (normalize_image(height_field) * 255.0).astype(np.uint8))


Cropping using both a python script as well as using GIMP as outlined above.
I feel this is a question more directed at the formatting of images in regards to the information extracted from the image files from the packages in the source code. The code itself is fine, it's more just a lack of understanding of how it works in order to determine why cropping an image gives me the error.
Apologies for how vague this is, I'm very new to python. Will happily add more information if required.
